# delay in update method in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a badminton simulator in unity, where the opponent is a set of video clips. I am trying to add some delay to my update method so theres some time between two clips of the opponent. However this delay only applies to the video clips and not the shuttle that arrives from behind the video.
My Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class Video_Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public VideoPlayer activeCam, otherCam;

    public List<VideoClip> playlist = new List<VideoClip>();

    public GameObject shuttle;


    VideoClip nextClip;
    private bool Timer;
    void Start()
    {
        Shuffle(playlist);
        // play the first video in the playlist
        PrepareNextPlaylistClip();
        SwitchCams(activeCam);
        Timer=false; 
        // setup an event to automatically call SwitchCams() when we finish playing
        activeCam.loopPointReached += SwitchCams;
        otherCam.loopPointReached += SwitchCams;
        shuttle.SetActive(false);
    
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (playlist.Count == 0)
                return;
        if(!Timer)
        {
            
            StartCoroutine(CountDown(5));
            
            if (nextClip == null && activeCam.time >= activeCam.clip.length - 0.1)
            {
                PrepareNextPlaylistClip();
                shuttle.SetActive(false);
            }
        
            if(activeCam.time >= 1.0f && activeCam.time <= 2.95f)
            {
                Debug.Log("start:"+activeCam.time);
                shuttle.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            //if(activeCam.time >= 2.95f || activeCam.time <= 1.0f)
            {
                Debug.Log("end:"+activeCam.time);
                shuttle.SetActive(false);
            }
        }


    }

    void SwitchCams(VideoPlayer thisCam)
    {
        activeCam = otherCam;
        otherCam = thisCam;
        activeCam.targetCameraAlpha = 1f;
        otherCam.targetCameraAlpha = 0f;
        
        Debug.Log("new clip: " + nextClip.name);
        nextClip = null;
    }

    void PrepareNextPlaylistClip()
    {

        nextClip = playlist[0];
        otherCam.clip = nextClip;
        otherCam.Play();
        playlist.RemoveAt(0);
    }


    //delay couroutine
    IEnumerator CountDown(float delay)
    {
        Timer = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        Timer= false;
    }
    // randomize the video playlist
    public static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> playlist)
    {
        int n = playlist.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = Random.Range(0, n);
            T value = playlist[k];
            playlist[k] = playlist[n];
            playlist[n] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding your code but rather than having it all in `Update()` couldn't you just have it in an `IEnumerator` like this?

```
void Start()
{ 
    Shuffle(playlist);
    // play the first video in the playlist
    PrepareNextPlaylistClip();
    SwitchCams(activeCam);        
    activeCam.loopPointReached += SwitchCams;
    otherCam.loopPointReached += SwitchCams;
    shuttle.SetActive(false);

    //Run the function on start
    StartCoroutine(Function());
}
IEnumerator Function()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(playlist.Count == 0)
            {
                //If you have no clips left exit out of the loop
                break;
            }
            if(nextClip == null)
            {
                //If you have clips left load the next clip
                shuttle.SetActive(false);
                PrepareNextPlaylistClip();
            }
            
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //This is your delay
            //Execute the code you want to run after the delay here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dosent really help as i need to access video clips timestamps which i cannot without putting it in update